# Odoo Qweb Report Footer on last Page only

Tags: python, pdf, odoo, pdf-generation, reporting

I need to make the **footer** of the pdf file on its last page only. Currently footer is on all pages and We need to make a single footer a report. I am attempting on **odoo sale order report** with no other customizations, just need to make the footer single only if the report has multiple pages. Please guide me

```xml
<template id="external_layout_footer">
<div class="footer">
    <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
        <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline">
            <li t-if="company.phone">Phone: <span t-field="company.phone"/></li>

            <li t-if="company.fax and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.fax">Fax: <span t-field="company.fax"/></li>

            <li t-if="company.email and company.fax or company.email and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.email">Email: <span t-field="company.email"/></li>

            <li t-if="company.website and company.email or company.website and company.fax or company.website and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
            <li t-if="company.website">Website: <span t-field="company.website"/></li>
        </ul>

        <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline" name="financial_infos">
            <li t-if="company.vat">TIN: <span t-field="company.vat"/></li>
        </ul>

        <t t-if="company.custom_footer">
            <span t-raw="company.rml_footer"/>
        </t>

        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li>Page:</li>
            <li><span class="page"/></li>
            <li>/</li>
            <li><span class="topage"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

what happening here is, this template is rendering for each pages in pdf id that file has one or more pages. I only need to make the footer on last page

Comment: I can't find the pdf page is the last one using template code. If I get any hint to find the generating pdf page is, last I can add restrictions for the footer. I updated My question with code for footer

Comment: I think you will need some javascript hacks here. Sorry that's not my speciality :-/

Comment: Thanks @CZoellner for your reply

Comment: Can we do any hacks on pdf-report engine odoo